# How do I centralise the contents in my h1 header

Tags: css, layout, styles, center

Currently my h1 contents are not able to be centered, can someone help me with this?

```
h1{
width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
color: rgb(5, 5, 5);
font-size:25px;
letter-spacing: 0px;
top: 0;

text-align: left;

padding: 10;
}h1:after
{
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    border:2px solid rgb(122, 119, 119);
}
```

This is my css and it is giving me this result
[image]

> UPDATE: This is my codes of the h1, i placed a wrong set of codes earlier

```
<div class="header">   
    <h1> <img src="/Physics Tutor/images/logo.jpg" height = "50">Physics Tutor Portal     
        <button><a href="Shiyun.html">Unanswered Question</a></button>
        <button><a href="index.html">Manage Quiz</a></button>
        <button><a href="Kim.html">Quiz Results</a></button>
        <button><a href="Yvonne.html">Student's Feedbacks</a></button>

        <style>

            button > a:hover {
              background-color: #df54d8;
            }

        </style>
    </h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is h1 is in your html

Comment: So sorry i put in the wrong codes, I have replaced it with the actual one

Comment: You cannot put img and button tags in h1. it gives validation errors. I think you will have to structure your code first.

Comment: I am trying to design a navigation bar, by using h1

Comment: Then, my issue is to move the whole "Physics Tutor Portal <buttons> <buttons>, to the middle of the logo. Currently it sticks to the border line of the h1, which I do not want that to happen

Comment: @ChamiM I am doing it this way just so that everything appears in h1 as a whole, as I meant it to be as a navigation bar, how should I structure it then?

Comment: @BasirLa Well... depends on the design. You could wrap h1 and the button from a parent element. and align them using flexbox.

Comment: @ChamiM thanks for the advice, it was great but now I am encountering another issue. Mind helping me take a look on this new question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59917105/how-do-i-make-css-affect-list-item-in-js-only-and-not-in-my-html

Answer (score 1):

You are using H2 but you are defining H1 in CSS. Replace H1 with H2 or H2 with H1.
After that define in CSS **text-align:center;**

Comment: Have tried modifying text-align to center instead of left, it still displays the same way

Answer (score 0):

pls check now. i changed code

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">   
    <h1>Physics Tutor Portal</h1>  
        <form>
          <button><a href="Shiyun.html">Unanswered Question</a></button>
          <button><a href="index.html">Manage Quiz</a></button>
          <button><a href="Kim.html">Quiz Results</a></button>
          <button><a href="Yvonne.html">Student's Feedbacks</a></button>
        </form>        
</div>
```

**css**

```
h1{
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: rgb(5, 5, 5);
    font-size:25px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    top: 0;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 10px;
}
h1:after{
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    border:2px solid rgb(122, 119, 119);
}
button > a:hover {
   background-color: #df54d8;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i placed the wrong h1 codes, would mind taking a look again?

Answer (score 0):

Your html tag mentioned in css is different and in JSX code is different.[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vahid_634/28rw5mcb/)

Change this. HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>Manage Quiz</h1> 
    <form id="add-cafe-form">
        <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="Quiz Question">
        <input type="text" name="right" placeholder="Right Answer">
        <input type="text" name="wrong" placeholder="Wrong Answer">
        <button>Add Question</button>
    </form>
    <ul id="esequiz-list"></ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    h1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
    h2{
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: rgb(5, 5, 5);
    font-size:25px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    top: 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10;
    }
    h2:after {
     content:' ';
     display:block;
     border:2px solid rgb(122, 119, 119);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I put in the wrong h1 codes, I have updated, would you mind helping me take a look again?

Comment: Yes, I am still not able to centralize the contents of h1, like in the image, the Text and buttons are still sticking to the bottom of the header

Comment: @BasirLa check now ...are you looking like this?

Comment: My page is still looking like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpMbZ.png

Comment: @BasirLa you want Physics tutor portal above all buttons?

Comment: no, i want the physics tutor portal, and the buttons, to move slightly higher, to be in the middle of the h1 bar, and not how it is sticked to the bottom like now @Vahid Akhtar